# CakePHP: Convert plain text to clickable link

Tags: cakephp

I'm still pretty new to CakePHP and am wondering if there is a built-in function that takes a string, looks for any URLs it may contain, and converts any URLs it finds into clickable links. I couldn't find anything in the CakePHP documentation and a quick Google search didn't find anything either. I know that CakePHP has some things that aren't fully documented, though. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1469/Text

Comment: I think the up to date link is http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/text.html

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this regex magic:

```php
$stringValue = 'bla blubb http://foobar.com test123';
$pregPattern = '/.*http:\/\/.*? .*/i';
$stringValue = preg_replace($pregPattern, '$1<a href="$2">$2</a>$3', $stringValue);
```

note: the '.*?' part can be improved by accepting URL encoded chars